# How I can remove items of ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, items

The apk is a memo pad or something like that. First you can put the title and then the note and if you press the button "Save" the note is saved and it saves in database. And if you press the button "Notes", you can view a list with all notes saved in database and you can select all notes and in the top of screen, you can read how many notes are selected. Ok, it's fine but I need remove notes when the are selected and I press the button with bin icon in the top menu.

The code:

```
package com.example.u2tarea3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class AnotacionesOpenHelperSingleton extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static AnotacionesOpenHelperSingleton instancia = null;
    private Context mCtx;

    public static AnotacionesOpenHelperSingleton getInstance(Context ctx){
        if(instancia == null){
            instancia = new AnotacionesOpenHelperSingleton(ctx);
        }               
        return instancia;
    }

    private AnotacionesOpenHelperSingleton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx,"anotaciones",null,2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase bd) {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

        sql.append("create table IF NOT EXISTS anotaciones (");
        sql.append("_id integer primary key autoincrement,");
        sql.append("texto text not null,");
        sql.append("fecha text not null)");
        bd.execSQL(sql.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase bd, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //bd.execSQL("drop table anotaciones");
        bd.execSQL("ALTER TABLE anotaciones ADD titulo text");
        bd.execSQL("UPDATE anotaciones SET titulo = 'sin titulo' WHERE titulo is NULL");

        onCreate(bd); 
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.example.u2tarea3;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editText;
    EditText editTitulo;
    Button btnGuardar;
    Button btnAnotaciones;
    SQLiteDatabase bd;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AnotacionesOpenHelperSingleton openHelperSingleton = AnotacionesOpenHelperSingleton.getInstance(this);
        bd = openHelperSingleton.getWritableDatabase();
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editTitulo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTitulo);
        btnGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);
        btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();

                valores.put("texto", editText.getText().toString());
                valores.put("fecha", sdf.format(c.getTime()));
                valores.put("titulo", editTitulo.getText().toString());
                bd.insert("anotaciones", null, valores);
                editText.setText("");

            }
        });
        btnAnotaciones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnotaciones);
        btnAnotaciones.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListAnotaciones.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.example.u2tarea3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListAnotaciones extends ListActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase bd;
    Cursor cursor;
    AnotacionesOpenHelperSingleton openHelperSingleton = AnotacionesOpenHelperSingleton
            .getInstance(this);
    int cont = 0;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bd = openHelperSingleton.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM anotaciones", null);

        try {
            String[] from = { "fecha", "titulo" };
            int[] to = { R.id.anotacionesFecha, R.id.anotacionesTitulo };

            final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.anotacion, cursor, from, to,
                    CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

            setListAdapter(adapter);
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(
                    new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0,
                                Menu arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0,
                                Menu arg1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            MenuInflater inflater = arg0.getMenuInflater();
                            inflater.inflate(R.menu.anotaciones, arg1);
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
                            switch(arg1.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.delete_id:


                            //arg0.finish();

                        default:
                            break;

                            }
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                                int position, long id, boolean checked) {

                            int seleccionados = getListView()
                                    .getCheckedItemCount();

                            switch (seleccionados) {
                            case 1:
                                mode.setTitle("1 nota seleccionada");
                                break;
                            default:
                                mode.setTitle("" + seleccionados
                                        + " notas seleccionadas");
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.anotaciones, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well do as you want. What is exactly your problem? If you can build a list then why can't you build a smaller list?

Comment: a smaller list? What do you mean?

Comment: If you want to remove items you will end with something smaller isn't it?

Comment: Sorry but I need to remove items of listview. I saw people use a arraylist and remove() to remove items but people create items in arraylist like arraylist.add("ítem 2") but I create items with a SimpleCursorAdapter and I dont know how I remove items.

Comment: It looks as if a SimpleCursorAdapter is not the right choise. Better put the result of your SELECT statement in an ArrayList and use an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Ok. I 'm going to try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the note from the database and the `ListView`, and then call `ListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

To delete from the `datasource` have a method in the class that deals with the `datasource`:

```
/**
 * Delete a note given an id.
 * @param id Key used to identify a note to delete.
 */
public void deleteNote(long id) {
    System.out.println("Note deleted with id: " + id);

    database.delete(ListOpenHelper.TABLE_MEMOS,
            ListOpenHelper.ID + " = " + id,
            null);
}
```

To refresh the `ListView` you could simply clear and re-add all the `Views` via the `ListViewAdapter`:

```
// Refresh adapter view with new data
ListAdapter.clear();
ListAdapter.addAll(dataSource.getAllNotes());
ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Alternatively remove only a single element from the `ListViewAdapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`.